# Modify NSBox or View on the fly

Tags: ios, xcode, view, nsbox

I am developing a project with WinDev Mobile for IOS. WM does not implement all the functionality I need, so I have to develop ObjC.

WM allows you to create a window on the fields "internal window" that displays the contents of another window.

I think that Objective C equivalent must be "NSBox".

I must assign to this NSBox (if I'm not mistaken) a view create by an external library.

The problem is that I do not know how to access this box because in the XCode project ( exported by WM) I can not find xib file or storyboard. The question is: how is it possible to access the current NSBox or find her name?

Comment: You can't use an NSBox in an iOS app, it's only for OS X.

Comment: Thank for your response, i'm newbie in ios, mac ... WM is a black box :( At that moment, WM has generated a subview !? Without xib and storyboard, how is it possible to find this view by programming from its name, eg CFI_carte